# Apply a set of default settings to calendar categories in Microsoft Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar

Does anybody know of a way to apply a set of default settings to calendar categories in Outlook? Say if I set an event to the "green" category, I would like the event to default to no reminder, private and show as free. Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to create a quick step to implement your requirements, but it didn't. For the example you cited, I'm afraid it can't be implemented directly in the outlook client. Because "no reminder, private and show as free" settings are created for the first time when you create a calendar item. With all due respect, you have to open this calendar item before making changes.